# scrollTop to the full height of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

The following code automatically scrolls to the bottom of the div and then back up across the time span of 5 seconds and then loops.

The problem I am having with it is that it does not recognize the scrollable/overflowing height of the div, just what I have set the standard height to. As it scrolls down it jumps to the bottom, while on the way up it slowly scrolls.

How do I alter the code so that it scrolls down as smoothly as it does up?

```js
function scroll(speed) {
  $('.name').animate({ scrollTop: $('.name').scrollTop() + $('.name').height() }, speed, function() {
   $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
  });
 }

 speed = 5000;

 scroll(speed);
 setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2);
```

```css
.name {
 -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 text-orientation: upright;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 font-family: 'digital';
 width: 16px;
 height: 87px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom,  rgba(245,245,245,1) 20%,rgba(100,100,100,1) 100%);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border:solid 1px #9effff; 
 margin-left: 7px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow: auto;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="name">abcdefghijkl</div>
<div class="name">abcdefg</div>
<div class="name">abcdefghijklmnopqrs</div>
<div class="name">abcdefghi</div>
```

Comment: "How do I alter the code so that it scrolls down as smoothly as it does up?" In my case it is smooth both on the way up and down o.O

Comment: @user3210641 yeah but notice how it scrolls down like 4 times faster than it scrolls up, that shouldn't happen!

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but they look about the same.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, to the people in the comments, look at how fast the smaller columns, columns 2 and 4 are moving, they hit the bottom far earlier than 1 and 3, however they all hit the top at the same time. This means they must be moving fast going down than up.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution:

```
function scroll(speed) {
    $('.name').each(function() {
      let $this = $(this), 
          st = $this.prop('scrollHeight') - $this.height();
      $this.animate({
        scrollTop: st,
      }, speed, function() {
        $this.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
      });
    })
}
```

[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/slaawwa/pen/bKYVvB)